# Equivalent lsim function from Matlab on Maxima

Tags: matlab, simulation, maxima

So I'm trying to find the equivalent for the *lsim* function on Maxima, trying to reproduce the results from this example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html. I'm using COMA library, defined a square wave function and multiplied it by the same transfer functions as the first example of the link above, using plot2d, but the results were totally different from expected. Anyone know a similar form for *lsim* to use on Maxima?

My Maxima code:

```
load(coma);

h(t) := (1 + signum(t))/2;
unitBox(t) := h(t+1/2) - h(t - 1/2);
squareWave(t, t0, p, d) :=
       unitBox(mod((t-t0)/p,1)/2/d);
ft(t) := ilt((s-1)/(s^2+s+5), s, t);

resp(t) := ft(t)*squareWave(t,0,4,0.5);
plot2d(
  resp(t),
  [t,0,15]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `ft` represents the unit impulse response, and you want `resp` to be the response to the square wave, is that right? If so, don't you want to define `resp` as the convolution of the unit impulse response and the square wave?

I am not very familiar with COMA so I would have to look up how to compute the convolution. If you agree that's what is needed, then we can figure that out.

By the way, it would others to understand the problem better if you would show exactly what is the actual and expected results, instead of assuming that they will figure it out. I was able to figure it out, but in general you can make it easier for others to help you by explicitly stating what was expected and actual.